# JPA class loading issue with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, intellij-idea

When I am attempting to fetch an entry from my database, the type returned from the EntityManager differs from the type specified in my code. They are both com.mycompany.Foo, but they have been instanciated with two different class loaders. I have found out that the class loader for the second type has repositories set to WEB-INF/classes/ with jarPath set to /WEB-INF/lib. 
This is all set up using JPA with Hibernate.

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>devResource</jta-data-source>
        <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

build.gradle with dependencies:

```
group 'testApplication'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.5.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.0.Final'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
}
```

The class fetching the entity:

```
@Stateless
public class FooService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Foo getFooEntity(final int id) {
        // Will throw a CastException since Foo is not Foo (loaded through different class loaders)
        return em.find(Foo.class, id);
    }
}
```

I am compiling this using IntelliJ (Exploded web application), could it be an issue with my deployment settings? They are currently being defined by Gradle through the war plugin.

Comment: This isn't caused by JPA/Hibernate so they can do little to this. This is caused by a wrong build. I'm not at all familiar with Gradle, but are you saying that there's a `com.mycompany.Foo` in both `/WEB-INF/classes` folder and in a JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the produced WAR file?

Comment: Where are you deploying this? Are you sure the jar containing the entities is not in the app server's classpath? Also, since it seems you're using EJBs, and thus a full-stack appserver, the app server should provide all these libraries, and they should thus be in the providedCompile or providedRuntime configuration.

Comment: This is deployed on a Glassfish application server. ´Foo´ is not in the ´WEB-INF/lib´ folder, it is only the class loader that has the jarPath set to the lib folder. providedCompile and provided runtime are those something I can set in the build information in IntelliJ or is it an application server specific thing? Edit: No, those are from Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the libraries that loads the libraries which scans for annotated @Entity classes is not in the lib folder for my domain. Moving the dependencies for my project to this folder fixed my issue.