# ClassCastException while using find() for javax.persistence.EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

While attempting to retrieve an Entity from a Database, using JPA's EntityManager, I am getting a ClassCastException that references two identical Classes. After reading other posts/articles, I suspect that the application using 2 different Class Loaders on the same Class type may be the culprit. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to verify nor correct this. Could someone help shine some light on this situation and its solution?

Entity **Member.java**

```
package com.example.mysql_flyway_database.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "_member_")
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer memberId;

    @Column(name = "member_name")
    private String memberName;

    public Integer getMemberId() {
        return memberId;
    }

    ... // other getter/setter methods

}
```

**persistence.xml** - stored in */resources/META-INF/*, in case this matters

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="Member" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.example.mysql_flyway_database.entities.Member</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JDND_C3"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="Keep1Moving2Forward3!"/>
        </properties>


    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**MyApplication**

```
...

private static void readMembersAsEntities(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    manager.getTransaction().begin();

    Member member = manager.find(Member.class, 1);
    System.out.println(String.format("Member %s was found", member.getMemberName()));
}

...
```

Here is the log:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mysql_flyway_database.entities.Member cannot be cast to com.example.mysql_flyway_database.entities.Member
    at com.example.mysql_flyway_database.MysqlFlywayDatabaseApplication.readMembersAsEntities(MysqlFlywayDatabaseApplication.java:51)
    at com.example.mysql_flyway_database.MysqlFlywayDatabaseApplication.main(MysqlFlywayDatabaseApplication.java:42)
    ... 5 more
```

> **Note:**
>   This is quite similar to the issue underlined here:
>
> [JPA class loading issue with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554121/jpa-class-loading-issue-with-hibernate).
>
> *Disclosure: I am fairly new to Spring and its plugins/dependencies (currently learning), so I am a bit lost on the provided solution described in the post mentioned. Regarding the solution mentioned in the provided post: In my project, I do not see /WEB-INF/lib.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Generally this happens when class loading is not managed correctly.

Comment: What would you suggest doing/changing to better manage this? Or, what things should I be aware of? @GauravJeswani

Comment: Check the class loaders if class is being loaded multiple times with different class loaders.

Comment: How do I check the Class Loaders? I have never done that before. @GauravJeswani

Comment: On which server your code is deployed?

Comment: It is being deployed locally. @GauravJeswani